# how to get all sentences which contain revision or track changes in Chinese\Japanese\Korean Word document with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to read a Chinese\Japanese\Korean Word document sentence by sentence  to find which sentence has track change or revision, and put these sentences which have track changes or revisions to another Word document's table.

For example, if one sentence has track change, then I will copy this sentence with format to that table's column 3 and column 4 in same row.
Then I will reject the track change in column 3 and accept track change in column 4.

The problem is I cannot get these Chinese\Japanese\Korean sentences' content but only "\r\a". So after I assign the sentence's formatted content to that table, only new line added in that table's cell, no other content.

The sample text:  노출의 안전성 이후(가 검토된 후) .

For example, here is a sentence: 노출의 안전성 이후(가 검토된 후) . In this sentence only 출 was marked with track change, I can get 출 with above code, but cannot get 노출의 안전성 이후(가 검토된 후). I want to get 노출의 안전성 이후(가 검토된 후), because in this sentence, one character 출 is in track change, not just 출.

You can add or delete the part of sample text with track change open and try it with below code:

```
            int sentenceCount = doc1.Sentences.Count;
            int i = 0;
            for (int s = 1; s <= sentenceCount; ++s)
            {
                i++;
                if (doc1.Sentences[s].FormattedText.Revisions.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (i <= tableRowCount)
                    {
                        doc2.Activate();
                        table.Cell(i, 3).Range.FormattedText = doc1.Sentences[s].FormattedText;
                        table.Cell(i, 4).Range.FormattedText = doc1.Sentences[s].FormattedText;
                        table.Cell(i, 3).Range.Revisions.RejectAll();
                        table.Cell(i, 4).Range.Revisions.AcceptAll(); 
                        //string sss = doc2.Sentences[s].Text;
                    }
                }
            }
            doc2.Save();
```

Could you please take a look and tell me why or any other solution if have? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem description isn't clear. What do you mean by "...only \r\a..." in the problem description? Also, it would help if you'd paste some sample text into the question so that we can test. For adding additional information please use the **[edit]** link below the question. Do *not* try adding this in a comment.

Comment: I have add more explanation and sample text in Korean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid your problem description is still unclear. `FormattedText` works for me in so far as I do get the Korean text. It appears Word is unsure what constitutes a *sentence* with the Korean content - it picks up more than just the Korean characters, but I do get the Korean. Perhaps it has to do with *where* in the document this text is located?

Comment: Sorry for confuse, I add an example for this.
By the way, the FormattedText can only get text with track change, right? If in a sentence, only one word be with track change, FormattedText cannot get this sentence but only this word, right?